# redirect to a different url

Tags: java, jsp

I have one application where i have three jsp pages, from index.jsp , control goes to process.jsp and after execution control goes to result.jsp to display data. But i want that instead of displaying data in result.jsp, control will go to another url so that that receiver url will get the requested data. that is: my url is 100.20.3.45:8085/myproject/index.jsp then after processing data i want that result should go to a different url of my same network i.e. `100.20.3.46`. How can I send the requested data to this different url?

Ex:

```
100.20.3.45:8085/myproject/index.jsp
```

goes to

```
100.20.3.45.8085/myproject/process.jsp
```

after processing control will go to `100.20.3.46`.

How can I send this data to a different url? what is this mechanism called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called "redirecting". It's to be achieved by [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

If you want to send additional data along, you'd need send it as request parameter(s) in a query string, but they will be visible in the URL in browser's address bar. If that isn't affordable, consider storing it in a shared datastore (database?) and then pass alone the unique key along.

Alternatively, you can also just let the `<form>` action URL point to that different host directly without the need for an intermediate JSP. As another alternative, you could also play for proxy yourself with help of for example `URLConnection`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: having controller/business logic in JSPs is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). I suggest to take some time to learn about [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: thanks for your reply but by response.sendRedirect(""), only it redirects but it does not contain any value to display, i am trying with this but getting any error:   String nextJSP = "/100.20.3.46/cy/process.jsp";
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
          dispatcher.forward(request,response);

Comment: You can't forward to a different host/domain. You can at highest forward to a different context. A real redirect is your best bet.

Comment: That's unanswerable as long as the concrete functional requirement is vague/unclear. But it's indeed quite good possible that you're simply looking for a solution in the wrong direction. In the future, try to ask how to solve a problem instead of how to achieve a solution of which you thought that it is the right solution to the real problem.

Comment: by response.sendRedirect("") i am only redirecting to a different page but can i show some value in that redirected page after processing? How it can be done?

Comment: As answered (did you check the updated answer?), just pass it as request parameter(s).

Comment: ok i am elaborating my problem here: i have index.jsp and from index.jsp control goes to a servlet and after processing data that it has got from index.jsp page control will redirect to a different page let's say: response.sendRedirect("result.jsp"); but instead of redirecting to this process.jsp, I want that control eill redirect to a different host and will display data there.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But why aren't you just submitting to that different host directly? Even more, why is the data supposed to be displayed on a different host in if that different host isn't involved in processing at all?

Comment: ya thanks i got you...let me try..if any problem will occur i will ask

Comment: i am facing one problem here how can i execute in a different host if that host is not in my LAN? it is a host on different place from same dns server,that different host is some where else but when i am giving url of that different host in my action then error is coming that it could not connect to that host.

Comment: Well, then you've just a network problem. This is not solveable with any Java code. Just report it to the network admin and get him to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

### Redirect to URL

```
window.location.href = "url"
```

### Examples of use

```
window.location.href = "/process_payment";
```

```
var username = @json($username);
window.location.href = '/' + username;
```

```
window.location.href = '/{{ $username }}';
```